# How to return List of strings from C# to Managed c++

Tags: c#, c++

Am adding C# dll as reference in managed C++, and calling C# function in c++ which returns list of strings

**C# code :**

```
namespace ManagedCSharp
{   
  public static class ManagedClass
    {
        public static List<string> ShowValue(void)
        {
            List<string> x = new List<string>();
            x.Add("1");

            return x;

        }
    }
}
```

**C++ Code:**

```
public ref class DoWork
    {
    public:void GetListOfStrings(void)
        {           
           //here i need to collect list of strings returned from C#
            (??) =  ManagedCSharp::ManagedClass::ShowValue();   
        }
    };
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you are using managed C++ you can simply use:

```
List<string>^ myvar = ManagedCSharp::ManagedClass::ShowValue();
```

Of course you will have to add the using directive for System::Collections.

Comment: List<String^>^ myvar = ManagedCSharp::ManagedClass::ShowValue();  use System::Collections::Generic

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd use C++/CLI for the interop. IMHO that makes life easy if you're mixing C++ and C# code.

Making namespaces explicit actually helps to make things clear in this case. C++ normally uses `std::string`, which can be converted to `char*`; C++/CLI uses `System::String`, which can be constructed (gcnew) from a `System::Char*` -- which are UTF-16 characters. To make the conversion, you need to apply an encoding, which can be found in `System::Text::Encoding::ASCII::GetString`. (or UTF-8 or whatever you use as your poison). It depends on what you put in your `std::string`.

Note that memory management in C++ and C# work quite differently. You still have to clean up your stuff on the unmanaged heap (if that applies); the constructor of `System::String` will simply copy the contents into a managed container.